# How to know how many requests to make without knowing amount of data on server

Tags: node.js, dynamic, server, promise, httprequest

I have a NodeJS application where I need to fetch data from another server (3rd-party, I have no control over it). The server requires you to specify a max number of entries to return, along with an offset. So for example if there are `100` entries on the server, I could request a `pageSize` of `100` and `offset` of `0`, or `pageSize` of `10`, and do 10 requests with `offset` 1,2,3, etc. and do a `Promise.all` (doing multiple concurrent smaller requests is faster when timing it).

```
var pageSize = 100;
var offsets = [...Array(totalItems / pageSize).keys()];
await Promise.all(offsets.map(async i => //make request with pageSize and offset));
```

The only problem is that the number of entries changes, and there is no property returned by the server indicating the total number of items. I could do something like this and `while` loop until the server comes back empty:

```
var offset = 0;
var pageSize = 100;

var data = [];
var response = await //make request with pageSize and offset
while (response is not empty){
   data.push(response);
   offset++;
   //send another request
```

But that isn't as efficient/quick as sending multiple concurrent requests like above.

Is there any good way around this that can deal with the dynamic length of the data on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Without the server giving you some hints about how many items there are, there's not a lot you can do to parallelize multiple requests as you don't really want to send more requests than are needed and you don't want to artificially make your requests for smallish number of items just so you can run more requests in parallel.

You could run some tests and find some practical limits.  What are the maximum number of items that the server and your client seem to be OK with you requesting (100? 1000? 10,000? 100,000?) and just request that many to start with.  If it indicates there are more after that, then send another request of a similar size.

The main idea with this is to minimize the number of separate requests and maximize the data you can get in a single call.  That should be more efficient than more parallel requests, each requesting fewer items, because its ultimately the same server on the other end and same data store that has to provide all the data so the fewest roundtrips in the fewest separate requests is probably the best.

But, some of this is dependent upon the scale and architecture of the target host so experiments will be required to see what practically works best.

Comment: I can send a request with a ridiculously large `pageSize` value that will return everything, but it will take a really long time. The server seems to be configured in such a way that sending multiple smaller requests is much faster. I was hoping to avoid having to use a loop and wait to see when the response is empty (end of data), as that defeats the purpose of the parallelization, but it looks like that may not be an option...